# Как получить base64 картинки из данных input - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, curl, mysqli

Есть форма загрузки изображений.

```
                <input type="file" name="pictures[]" class="text-white my-1">
```

Нужно закодировать картинку в base64 для дальнейшей отправки по cURL на [imgbb](https://imgbb.com)

```
        $ch = curl_init("https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=*персоннальный ключ обитает здесь...*");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $base64);

        $feedback = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как обычно, при сохранении мы используем `$_FILES` для этого. И в форме, значением атрибута `name` не должно быть массовом. Запишем в файл, и уже после кодируем.

```
$name =  $_FILES['pictures']['name']; 
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/' .  $name . '.png', $_FILES['pictures']['tmp_name']);

$base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' .  $name . '.png'));
```